# How to solve the Oracle DB trigger error?

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers, database-trigger

I wrote a DB trigger to monitor an insert action. After inserting a new record, I would like to automatically set the `CREATION_DATE` to `sysdate`.

I get an error when I want to insert a new record:

> error
>   ORA-04091: table REPORT is mutating, trigger/function may not
>   see it
>   ORA-06512: at "CREATION_DATE_TEST", line 2
>   ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'CREATION_DATE_TEST'

My code:

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER creation_date_test 
 AFTER INSERT ON REPORT FOR EACH ROW 
 BEGIN  
   UPDATE REPORT set CREATION_DATE = sysdate
   WHERE ROWID = :new.ROWID;
 END;
```

I also tried to replace `ROWID = :new.ROWID` with `PROJECT_ID = new.PROJECT_ID`. It throws the same error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you just want a before insert trigger that sets the `:new.creation_date`

```
create or replace trigger creation_date_test
  before insert on report
  for each row
begin
  :new.creation_date := sysdate;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Your answer really helpful!!

Comment: @deli - Is `creation_date` a `varchar2` rather than a `date` as the name would imply?  I wouldn't expect there to be any strings used in the code I posted.

Comment: I have changed the data type now. Thanks !!